# Apache 2.4 on Windows hangs for 20 seconds after being idle

Tags: apache

I have Apache running on a Windows 10 VM on my laptop. If my Apache server sits idle for a while, around 5 minutes idle, them my next request takes around 20 seconds. Subsequent requests take milliseconds. This happens for all Apache requests, even images and 404s. I set my LogLevel trace6 to try to figure out what's going on.

The logging output below is for one of these slow requests. You can see the 12th line is about 20 seconds delayed from the previous line. It looks like the hang up has something to do with authorization. I'm also including my config output from server-status for the mod_authz_core.c module. I have not enabled HostNameLookups.

I've also tried setting

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Which is often suggested as a fix for slow Apache on Windows, but that did not help.

```html
1  [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.361111 2017] [filter:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_filter.c(168): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] Content-Type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' ...
2  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [core:trace5] [pid 3004:tid 1072] protocol.c(643): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] Request received from client: GET /index.cfm?event=home HTTP/1.1
3  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(419): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] Headers received from client:
4  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Host: mydevsite.local
5  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Connection: keep-alive
6  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
7  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
8  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
9  [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
10 [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
11 [Thu Aug 10 16:21:41.705842 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_request.c(422): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Cookie: blah-blah-removed
12 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.716531 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
13 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.716898 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
14 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.716898 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /index.cfm
15 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.737002 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
16 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.737002 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
16 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:02.737002 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /index.htm
18 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.249955 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
19 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.249955 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
20 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.249955 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /views/home.cfm
21 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.288220 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
22 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.288220 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
23 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.288220 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /views/header.cfm
24 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.305888 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
25 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.305888 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
26 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.305888 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /views/navigation.cfm
27 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.324906 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
28 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.324906 2017] [authz_core:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_authz_core.c(806): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
29 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.324906 2017] [core:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] request.c(291): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /views/template.cfm
30 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.361111 2017] [filter:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_filter.c(174): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] ... matched 'text/html'
31 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.361111 2017] [filter:trace2] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_filter.c(185): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] Content-Type condition for 'deflate' matched
32 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace3] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(1086): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] Response sent with status 200, headers:
33 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace5] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(1095): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 21:21:41 GMT
34 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace5] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(1098): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Win64) mod_jk/1.2.41
35 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Content-Language: en-US
36 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Expires: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 21:22:04 GMT
37 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Pragma: no-cache
38 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Vary: Accept-Encoding
39 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Content-Encoding: gzip
40 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
41 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Connection: Keep-Alive
42 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
43 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [http:trace4] [pid 3004:tid 1072] http_filters.c(916): [client 192.168.26.1:63869]   Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
44 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.363823 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1072] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
45 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.364202 2017] [deflate:debug] [pid 3004:tid 1072] mod_deflate.c(851): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 70382 to 15199 : URL /index.cfm
46 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.364202 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1072] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63869] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
47 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.390910 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1064] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63870] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
48 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.390910 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1080] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63872] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
49 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.390910 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1076] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63873] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
50 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.391895 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1084] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63871] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
51 [Thu Aug 10 16:22:04.391895 2017] [core:trace6] [pid 3004:tid 1068] core_filters.c(523): [client 192.168.26.1:63874] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In proof reading my question, I think I've found the answer. The stock httpd-info.conf file has `Require host .example.com` lines in it. Looks like I left those in there when I added my ip based restrictions. The `host` lines will cause HostNamelookups to be on. I've removed the example.com lines, and I've now tested it through two idle cycles and it's been responsive with no delay both times.

Sometimes you just have to explain it to see the problem. :-)